# script para modificar misma tabla en 3 bases Mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqldb

Necesito crear un script para modificar el atributo de un campo a "UNIQUE" en 3 bases del mismo entorno, en tablas con el mismo nombre.
La idea es ejecutar ese script desde la consola de Mysql, y que si lo corro nuevamente no de error, a lo sumo no se ejecute.

Ej. :

1. En el mismo esquema tengo las bases base1 , base2, base3
2. Dentro de cada base tengo la misma tabla libros creada con el siguiente script .

```html
CREATE TABLE `libros` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `pais_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `codigo` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Desde un uníco script, necesito correr la sentencia, mismo nombre de tabla pero en bases distintas:
ALTER TABLE libros ADD UNIQUE (codigo)

Asi funciona correctamente :
USE base1;
ALTER TABLE libros ADD UNIQUE (codigo);
USE base2;
ALTER TABLE libros ADD UNIQUE (codigo);
USE base3;
ALTER TABLE libros ADD UNIQUE (codigo);

El problema es que este script me genera automaticamente un indice UNIQUE con el nombre del campo, en este caso : codigo
Si lo vuelvo a ejecutar, vuelve a crear el indice, sumándole un incremental al nombre : codigo_1 codigo_2 codigo_3

Como podria hacer ..
para que si el nombre de indice codigo ya existe, omita volver a crear un nuevo indice ?

Comment: Ejecuto esa instrucción múltiples veces y no da error aunque el índice ya esté creado. ¿Puedes modificar la pregunta añadiendo el error que obtienes?

Comment: Gracias por ver el tema. Quizas me falto aclarar, en el mismo script necesito ejecutar ALTER TABLE libros ADD UNIQUE (codigo) , y que modifique la tabla libros en 3 bases distintas. Pongo USE base1 y codigo, pero solo me ejecuta el primer script, no se como es la sintaxis correcta

Comment: ahi edité la explicación

Comment: Pasa que cuando colocas el punto y coma luego del nombre de la base estás cometiendo un error de sintaxis, ¿has usado T-SQL? El punto y coma en MySQL es como el GO en T-SQL. Déjalo así: `USE base1 ALTER TABLE libros ADD UNIQUE (codigo);`

Comment: Le saque el ; y me da error , lo copio :

USE base1
ALTER TABLE libros ADD UNIQUE (codigo);

USE base2
ALTER TABLE libros ADD UNIQUE (codigo);

USE base1
ALTER TABLE libros ADD UNIQUE (codigo)
MySQL ha dicho: Documentación
#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'ALTER TABLE libros ADD UNIQUE (codigo)' en la linea 2

Comment: Finalmente encontré la forma y edité la pregunta. El problema ahora es que x defecto me crea un indice unique con el nombre del  campo. Necesito que si el nombre de indice ya existe no cree uno nuevo ..